# How to draw wavy line pattern using graphics?

Tags: javascript, p5.js

I'm trying to draw this wavy pattern using p5.js

I tried using a sine wave, but notice sine waves don't have a the peaks vertical and are pointed

Is there a way to do this with using mathematical functions?

Or should I manually draw this by traversing a point vertically + making semi circle peaks manually and so on

[image: wavy pattern]

I would also like to build upon this wavy pattern and put it inside shapes and maybe skew it in a curved shape

[image]

Comment: Can't help you with wavy pattern, but I have solution about using it inside shape, here are the answers:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57546467/is-it-possible-to-make-canvas-with-background-with-lines-or-canvas-that-isnt-a